# ¿Cómo duplicar la fila anterior con un ID diferente y en caso de que no haya ninguna crear la primera fila?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
var ultima_celda=$("table tr:last");
$("table tr:last").append(ultima_celda);
```

Lo que hace es duplicar exactamente la última fila, no obstante, necesito poder modificar algunos datos. Aquí les dejo un ejemplo de una fila con todas sus celdas, incluido el botón para eliminarla.

```
<tr class="fila">
  <td class="tfsize">
    <a href="" class="update fila sinEspacio editable editable-click" data-name="name" data-type="text" data-pk="1" data-sid="1" data-cid="1" data-d="lunes" data-h="500" data-title="Ingresar valor">05:00</a>
  </td>
  <td class="tfsize">
    <a href="" class="update fila sinEspacio editable editable-click" data-name="name" data-type="text" data-pk="1" data-sid="1" data-cid="2" data-d="lunes" data-h="500" data-title="Ingresar valor">645</a>
  </td>
  <td class="tfsize">
    <a href="" class="update fila sinEspacio editable editable-click" data-name="name" data-type="text" data-pk="1" data-sid="1" data-cid="3" data-d="lunes" data-h="500" data-title="Ingresar valor">302</a>
  </td>
  <td class="tfsize">
    <a href="" class="update fila sinEspacio editable editable-click" data-name="name" data-type="text" data-pk="1" data-sid="1" data-cid="4" data-d="lunes" data-h="500" data-title="Ingresar valor">27</a>
  </td>
  <td class="tfsize">
    <a href="" class="update fila sinEspacio editable editable-click" data-name="name" data-type="text" data-pk="1" data-sid="1" data-cid="7" data-d="lunes" data-h="500" data-title="Ingresar valor">400</a> </td>
  <td class="tfsize">
    <!-- $fila->columna_id -->
    <span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmDeletion">
      <button id="delete-button-4" class="deleteFila btn btn-xs btn-danger sinEspacio text-white" data-toggle="modal" data-sid="1" data-d="lunes" data-h="500" data-target="#exampleModal" data-placement="bottom" title="Eliminar" onclick=""><i class="material-icons md-10">delete</i></button>
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Necesito poder modificar el valor de la primera celda, es decir, el **05:00** por +30 min o 60 min. Además necesito poder modificar el **data-h="500"** por **data-h="550"** o **data-h="600"** (correspondiente a 05:30 0 06:00 pero esto es algo interno mío). El resto de los "data-x" deben quedar exactamente con el mismo valor.

El procedimiento sería algo así:

```
Si existe alguna fila en el tbody, entonces:
    var ultima_celda=$("table tr:last");
    ultima_celda.firstcell.value = ultima_celda.firstcell.value + 60 min;
    por cada celda de ultima_celda hacer:
    celda.data-h = celda.data-h + 100;
    $("table tr:last").append(ultima_celda);
Else
   crearprimerafila();
```

¿Me pueden orientar, por favor?

Comment: Debes empezar arreglando tu código para duplicar filas, pues no es correcto aún. Sólo duplica las columnas, no las filas. Además lo estas agregando **dentro** de la fila actual, no en una nueva, y además solo lo agrega debajo de la fila que ya conoce como la última, no sobre las nuevas porque son dinámicas y no estás gestionandolo bien.  Cuando hayas superado eso y corregido la pregunta miramos el resto, pues ya partimos de una mala base.

Comment: Sinceramente no tengo idea de frontend, la "mala base" que comentas es el resultado de otra pregunta hecha en stackoverflow. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/534700/c%c3%b3mo-a%c3%b1adir-una-fila-en-una-tabla-html-con-los-datos-de-la-anterior/534704?noredirect=1#comment948376_534704 ¿podrías ayudarme?

Comment: Esa respuesta ni es completa ni es correcta por lo que he dicho antes. Son demasiadas cosas a realizar a la vez y este tipo de preguntas no benefician a nadie más.  Haz tus preguntas limitandolas a un solo problema a la vez, porque sino parece que estemos trabajando para ti dándote una solución que nadie más va a buscar.  Empieza con la pregunta de como duplicar la última fila, y cuando tengas una respuesta certera que hayas comprobado entonces pon otra de como modificar sus datos.

Comment: Ya he empezado por esa.. te he pasado el link en el comentario anterior.

Comment: Ya, pero en los comentarios dices esto: `En otras palabras, necesito que antes de hacer "append" podes editar la hora (sumandole +1 h) y sino existe ninguna fila que la cree porque sino hay nada no clona nada.` lo cual nos remite a esta pregunta.  Además, dices que quieres crear una fila si no existe ninguna, pero no dices que estructura debe tener.  Centrate en un problema cada vez y una vez tengas la solución haz la pregunta siguiente, de este modo será útil a los demás. Si vas cambiando el escenario inicial de la pregunta es un lio porque la respuesta tambien cambia y no es util

Comment: Y entiendo que no sepas del frontend, pero venir a copiar/pegar soluciones no es el objetivo del sitio, que es aprender entre todos. Si no buscas aprender entonces a mi personalmente no me motiva responderte, la verdad, debes mostrar esfuerzo en ello e investigación por tu parte en cada pregunta, sino son simples tareas que debería estar haciendo un programador de pago.

Comment: ¿Cómo que no digo la estructura de la fila? puse un ejemplo exacto de cómo tienen que ser las filas. Siempre publico aquí cuando he investigado y no he llegado a nada. Si ni te molestes en seguir respondiendo si no tienes la intención de ayudar.

Comment: Si te digo todo esto es para ayudarte, no para tocarte las narices. He corregido la indentación del código de tu pregunta porque al leerla pensé que tambien era pseudocódigo, pues todo quedaba indentado fuera de la vista a lo largo y no se me ocurrio mover la barra de abajo y pense que ni cerrabas las columnas pues quedaban fuera de la indentación normal.

Comment: ahora dime, ¿eso que has puesto seria la fila 0 en caso de que no hubiera ninguna más?  ¿Empezaria por las 05:00 y con esos valores?  A eso me referia cuando decia que no has dicho la estructura, pues no estoy seguro si quieres empezar a esa hora con esos valores o son solo un ejemplo como dices en la pregunta

Comment: Bueno, he publicado una respuesta a pesar de todo, para que veas que mi intención era ayudar, y disculpa si te has sentido ofendido, a veces soy demasiado directo con lo que pienso y como pienso que deberian ser las cosas en este sitio, pues me rijo por las normas de [ask] y si no lo veo claro lo digo también.

Comment: Gracias, @masterguru. Sí, me ha tocado un poco tu respuesta porque yo suelo preguntar aquí cuando no me quedan opciones. Considero que la estructura de la fila la he dado y el mal ejemplo es resultado de otra pregunta que hice posteriormente (subdividir el problema en subproblemas) pero hasta ahora no he logrado nada. Gracias por tu respuesta, la voy a probar en un rato. Estoy seguro que este código ayudará a mucha gente porque es interesante la funcionalidad de añadir filas en una tabla dinámicamente y, normalmente, siempre hay que cambiar algún valor (normalmente el id). Gracias de nuevo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta es mi propuesta de solución para tu pregunta. El código está comentado y es autoexplicativo. He usado el elemento HTML [template](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) y la interfaz [documentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) para la generación de las filas.

```js
function duplicarFila() {
  // analizamos si es la primera fila o no
  if($("table tr").length > 0) {
        // definimos intervalo
        let intervalo = 50
    // leemos el dato anterior
    tiempo = $("table tr:last").find("a").first("a").attr('data-h');
    // sumamos el intervalo que deseamos
    tiempo = parseInt(tiempo) + intervalo
    // creamos fila
    crearFila(tiempo)
  } else {
    // si es la primera creamos fila con valor inicial
    crearFila('0')
  }
}

function crearFila(hour) {
  // añadimos ceros a la izquierda
  let valor4digitos = hour.toString().padStart(4, "0")
  // partimos en dos trozos de 2 caracteres la cadena de 4 dígitos anterior
  let trozos = $(valor4digitos.match(/.{2}/g))
  // convertimos el 50 en 30 para representar la mediahora
  if(trozos[1] == 50) trozos[1] = 30
  // establecemos la hora
  let hora = trozos[0] + ":" + trozos[1]
  // asignamos a un objeto jquery el DOM de la plantilla
  const plantillaFila = $(document.getElementById('plantilla-fila').content);
  // creamos un fragmento en memoria
  const fragment = $(document.createDocumentFragment());
  // modificamos la hora
  plantillaFila.find("a[data-cid='1']").html(hora)
  // modificamos el atributo data-h en todos los enlaces <a>
  plantillaFila.find("a").attr('data-h', valor4digitos)
  // clonamos la plantilla en una nueva variable
  const clone = plantillaFila.clone(true)
  // agregamos el clon en el fragmento
  fragment.append(clone)
  // agregamos el fragmento en la tabla
  $("table").append(fragment)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="duplicarFila()">
  Duplicar fila o iniciar filas
</button>

<table></table>

<template id="plantilla-fila">
  <tr class="fila">
    <td class="tfsize">
      <a href="" class="update fila sinEspacio editable editable-click" data-name="name" data-type="text" data-pk="1" data-sid="1" data-cid="1" data-d="lunes" data-h="500" data-title="Ingresar valor">05:00</a>
    </td>
    <td class="tfsize">
      <a href="" class="update fila sinEspacio editable editable-click" data-name="name" data-type="text" data-pk="1" data-sid="1" data-cid="2" data-d="lunes" data-h="500" data-title="Ingresar valor">645</a>
    </td>
    <td class="tfsize">
      <a href="" class="update fila sinEspacio editable editable-click" data-name="name" data-type="text" data-pk="1" data-sid="1" data-cid="3" data-d="lunes" data-h="500" data-title="Ingresar valor">302</a>
    </td>
    <td class="tfsize">
      <a href="" class="update fila sinEspacio editable editable-click" data-name="name" data-type="text" data-pk="1" data-sid="1" data-cid="4" data-d="lunes" data-h="500" data-title="Ingresar valor">27</a>
    </td>
    <td class="tfsize">
      <a href="" class="update fila sinEspacio editable editable-click" data-name="name" data-type="text" data-pk="1" data-sid="1" data-cid="7" data-d="lunes" data-h="500" data-title="Ingresar valor">400</a> </td>
    <td class="tfsize">
      <!-- $fila->columna_id -->
      <span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmDeletion">
        <button id="delete-button-4" class="deleteFila btn btn-xs btn-danger sinEspacio text-white" data-toggle="modal" data-sid="1" data-d="lunes" data-h="500" data-target="#exampleModal" data-placement="bottom" title="Eliminar" onclick=""><i class="material-icons md-10">delete</i></button>
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

A partir de aquí se puede hacer lo que se quiera con los **id** que se repitan y lo que haga falta para modificar la plantilla inicial.

Dejo a tu cargo la filtración de las horas, pues debes evitar que pasen de las 23:59 si pulsan demasiadas veces el botón.

Comment: no logro que me funcione. He agregado el tag "template" justo antes de cerrar la etiqueta "tbody", es decir, <table><thead></thead><tbody> //todos mis datos <template></template></tbody></table> ¿crees que sea correcto?

Comment: Muchas gracias, @masterguru. Ya funciona perfectamente. Me gustaría preguntarte una cosa más.. ¿Cuál es el camino correcto a seguir en caso de tener más de una tabla (diferentes) en una misma pantalla? tengo que crear un "duplicarFilas" y un "crearFila" por cada tabla? porque el template está claro que sí, pero duplicar las funciones anteriormente mencionadas me parece un poco "parche" ¿hay alguna forma de obtener el template cuyo botón haya sido presionado? en otras palabras ¿es posible que con esas dos funciones pueda crear filas de diferentes tablas dependiendo el botón presionado?

Comment: Sí, en realidad son 7 tablas (sé que no es lo ideal pero es lo tengo que hacer). Entonces hay 7 tablas en una misma pantalla y cada una tiene su botón de "agregar fila". Lo que intenté preguntarte en el comentario anterior era si había posibilidad de que cada uno de esos botones llamara a la misma función y que ésta detectara cuál botón había sido presionado para crear la fila en una tabla u otra, pero creo que finalmente copiaré y pegaré 14 veces. (2 funciones por tabla). Estoy muy agradecido contigo, muchas gracias.

Comment: Ahora lo que me falta por resolver es notificar a mi servidor de la creación de las filas, supongo que habrá que llamar a una función que haga una petición a través de ajax

Comment: Consulta este enlace para verlo en dos tablas: https://jsfiddle.net/pah3m0t5/  (fijate que he quitado una de las funciones de la respuesta para integrar lo del calculo de la hora dentro del switch)

Comment: Muy útil, lo probaré. Muchas gracias.

Comment: ui, hay un error en ese fiddle... donde pone esto: `tiempo = $("table tr:last").` deberia poner esto: `tiempo = $("#" + tabla + " tr:last")`

Comment: Me gusta mucho tu solución, pero lo raro es que cuando quiero hacer clic en "añadir" de una tabla, cuando le doy al "añadir de otra" no lo coge a la primera. ¿Qué crees que pueda estar causando esto? Yo sólo he quitado el "switch" de crearFila() porque a todas las tablas se les debe modificar la hora y nada más.

Comment: No se, si no lo veo no estoy seguro de lo que has hecho.  Ponlo en un fiddle para que lo pueda reproducir y ver que ocurre.

Comment: teniendo en cuenta que me ayudaste muchísimo con esto y que ahora tengo una duda ¿serías tan amable de echarme un cable? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/541811/c%c3%b3mo-duplicar-una-fila-de-una-tabla-y-que-tambi%c3%a9n-se-dupliquen-los-estilos-de-l

Comment: uf, voy muy mal de tiempo, lo siento... si lo miro será a partir del dia 26, estoy viajando estos dias... si no lo has conseguido por entonces dame el toque de nuevo

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarte la molestia de responderme. Disfruta tu viaje. Te avisaré en caso de no poder resolverlo :)